How to combine response of 2 results using Node.js
The below code is to get the user list associated with particular id and this service.ts file.
async getId(id:number){
//below code will give us participants list based on id
let participants = await this.participantRepo.findById(id)

//here I am looping each participant to get their profile picture if it's available
   for (const participant of participants) {
      let result = await this.profilePictureService.getprofilePicture(participant.user);
      //here in **result** I will get profile picture of each user if it's available
    }

const [internalParticipants, externalParticipants] = _partition(
      participants,
      (p: CampParticipants) => p.participantRoleId !== ParticipantRoleEnum.External
    );

 return {
      internalParticipants,
      externalParticipants,
    };

}

Sample response for participants:
{
  "internalParticipants": [
    {
      "id": 515,
      "userId": 126,      "
      "participantRoleId": 1,
      "user": {
        "id": 126,
        "firstName": "Test1",
        "lastName": "Test",
        "mail": "test@home.com",
       }
    },
    {
      "id": 515,
      "userId": 1219,
      "participantRoleId": 2,
       "user": {
        "id": 1219,
        "firstName": "Rob",
        "lastName": "const",
        "mail": "rob.const@home.com",        
      }
    }
],
  "externalParticipants": []
}

Sample response for profile picture:
{
"photoName": "profile-picture.png",
"buffer": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDgAAAQ4CAYAAADsEGyPAAAAAXNSR0IArc"
}

Suppose if we have profile picture associated only with "userId": 126, how to merge both response to get result as below?
How to combine profile picture response with participants list response?
**

FinalResponse/output response

**
{
  "internalParticipants": [
    {
      "id": 515,
      "userId": 126,      "
      "participantRoleId": 1,
      "user": {
        "id": 126,
        "firstName": "Test1",
        "lastName": "Test",
        "mail": "test@home.com",
       }
      "photoName": "profile-picture.png",
      "buffer": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDgAAAQ4CAYAAADsEGyPAAAAAXNSR0IArc"
    },
    {
      "id": 515,
      "userId": 1219,
      "participantRoleId": 2,
       "user": {
        "id": 1219,
        "firstName": "Rob",
        "lastName": "const",
        "mail": "rob.const@home.com",        
      }
    },
  "externalParticipants": []
}


for (let [index, participant] of participants.entries()) {
  let result = await this.profilePictureService.getprofilePicture(
    participant.user
  );
  if (result) participants[index] = { ...participants[index], ...result };
}

You can use spread operator of javascript if profile picture is available for a perticular user it this will add profile picture's data in participants's array

above code works fine, after adding this code test cases are failing with the below error, any idea what's wrong?   Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NestContainer'
    |     property 'modules' -> object with constructor 'ModulesContainer'
    |     property 'InternalCoreModule' -> object with constructor 'Module'
    --- property 'container' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)

  at messageParent (node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/messageParent.js:29:19)


You are attempting to store the entire response object, which is a complex data structure with circular dependencies, as described in the error notice (TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON).
What you should do is either map the data you need instead of storing the entire circular object.
Alternatively, you should check into various libraries that can parse circular JSON: https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted

 let internalParticipants = participants.map(async (pt) => {
              pt.image = await this.profilePictureService.getprofilePicture(pt.user)
              return pt; 
            }));

You can map through participants which will add an additional key image which will contain image response object & assign it to any variable. Or else if you want to seperate it out just change logic to below inside map.
let image = await this.profilePictureService.getprofilePicture(pt.user)
pt.photoName = image.photoName;
pt.buffer= image.buffer;
return pt;

then at the end return it like
return {
 internalParticipants 
}

Hope it's more clear now.

But this return pt response will not get merged with final participants response ? As I shown in the final response !?

I want to combine participants and profile picture response w.r.t userId

@mplungjan Added my edits. I thought based on his question it's self explanatory.

@userrj_vj_051620 I've made the changes, and now instead of participants we are returning map response in the return statement which will do as you requested.
